# Como hacer una consulta a 27 base de datos con la misma estructura

Tags: php, sql-server, php7

tengo 27 bases de datos que tienen la misma estructura, estas 27 bases de datos las tengo en un grupo donde puedo consultar las 27 bases de datos con un solo Query
Ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

todos tiene una ip diferente, pero la consulta es la misma para todas las bases de datos, cuando yo doy click derecho sobre puntos de venta, nueva consulta-->y pongo este Query

Ejemplo

```
use db_name
select  *
from Detalle
where Codigo = 'Numero a consultar'
order by Detalle desc
```

como resultado obtengo los datos de cada base de datos.

lo que necesito hacer una conexion desde PHP que  este dirigia a las 27 bases de datos, es decir que cuando haga una consulta de cualquier tipo  me muestre los resultados de las 27 bases de datos.

"Todas las 27 bases de datos tienen la mismas tablas, los mismos triggers, y sps"

Comment: Necesitas un usuario que tenga permisos en las 27 bases de datos.. y hacer 27 unions con un select a cada base... lo intentaste?

Comment: Podrías por favor darme un ejemplo, porque ya intente y todo en SQL Server funciona, pero con PHP no.

Comment: El query es el mismo en sql server que en php. seria una union de ese query que tenes, pero en el from aclarar a que base pertenece la tabla.

Comment: Entiendo a lo que te refieres, pero tengo una duda, si le especifico al from a que tabla pertence no me traeria nada o saldria error, ya que en la conexión tengo definida es un solo punto, lo que necesito es a los 27

Comment: Por eso te dije. El usuario que se conecta tiene que tener acceso a las 27 bases y las bases tienen que tener permisos de lectura entre ellas. Esto es algo que se define en la db, no hay un ejemplo para ello que te pueda dar de codigo. es funcionalidad propia.

Comment: Si, el usuario ya esta definido , tiene permisos en todas las bases de datos, todos los permisos los tiene, ya que es el dia a dia sobre el trabajo entonces como mas podria validar, e inlcuso intente hacer una variable global que contuviera todas las conexiones, pero me arroja error

Comment: es este el que me arroja Argument 2 passed to sqlsrv_connect() must be of the type array, string given in

Comment: Cuando vos te conectas a una base con un usuario con permisos para varias, y las bases se ven entre ellas, tendrias acceso a las mismas. Creo que te convendria leer un manual de slqserver para entender esto. Esto no es un problema de php ni nada de eso.

Comment: He estado indagando sobre el tema, e incluso cree un servidor central para hacer la conexion, pero ni asi funciono. depronto no tenes algun manual? video? ejemplo? ya lo has realizado? si no es mucho pedir

Comment: No, Se la teoria pero no lo realice. Supongo que google podra ayudar.

Comment: Aaah ok, si me he apoyado bastante en el motor de busqueda, pero hasta ahora nada similar... es mas, ni con MySQL existe!

Comment: fijate aca: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512978/how-to-connect-to-two-databases-at-the-same-time-in-sql-server o aca: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144051/73749. tenes que linkear las bases de datos (como te dije mas arriba)

Comment: Vale, lo voy a revisar e intetar, si lo logro hacer te estare contando y incluyendo el codigo fuente, a alguien mas le podria servir

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
<?php 

class conn{
    // connexion
    private $conn= null;
    // datos de conexion
    private $db = array("user" => "sa",
                        "pass" => "Newm00n");
    // database a usar
    private $database = null;

    //WIN-72MAJ7LGIAV\SQLEXPRESS

    // constructor con base de datos default
    public function __construct($database="master"){

        $this->database = $database;
        // seleccionamos base de datos;
        self::select_db($this->database);
    }

    private function select_db($database){
        // creamos una nueva conexion
        $this->conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=192.168.100.187,1433;Database={$database}", $this->db["user"], $this->db["pass"]);
        // configuramos opciones
        $this->conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
        $this->conn->setAttribute( PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, 1 );  
    }

    private function all_db(){

        // diferentes opciones para selecciona todas la base de datos
        $query = "SELECT name FROM sys.databases d WHERE d.database_id > 6";
        //$query = "SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')";

        //ejecutamos la query
        $stmt = $this->conn->query($query);
        // creamos arreglo
        $data = array();
        // hacemos un loop para los resultados
        while ( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){ 
            // los agregamos al arreglo data
           $data[] = $row['name'];  
        }
        // retornamos data
        return $data;
    }

    public function getdata($number){
        $data =array();

        // recorremos cada resultado de all_db()
        foreach (self::all_db() as $value) {
            // seleccionamos el nombre de la base de datos
            $db = $value;
            // creamos un nuevo arreglo para esa key
            $data[$db] = array();
            // cambios de base de datos
            self::select_db($db);
            // original query
        $query = "SELECT  * FROM detalle WHERE Codigo = '{$number}' ORDER BY Detalle DESC";

        // my test query!
        $query = "SELECT  * FROM detalle WHERE id = '{$number}'";

            // ejecutamos query
            $stmt = $this->conn->query($query);

            // recorremos los resultados
            while ( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){ 
                // agregamos al arreglo db la data de esa base de datos
                $data[$db][] = $row;  
            }
        }
        // retornamos la data
        return $data;
    }

    // destruimos la conexion
    public function __destruct() {
          $this->conn = null;
    }

}

echo "<pre>";

$conn = new conn();
$data = $conn->getdata(1);

print_r($data);

?>
```

**resultado:**

```
Array
(
    [test1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => user1
                )

        )

    [test2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => user2
                )

        )

    [test] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => user
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo, ya mismo me pongo a validar la informacion suministrada, y te estare contando